# Regex is not accepting uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing URL Validation for input field.

Below is the regex being used for the validation. But it is not accepting uppercase letters for https.

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

we can make the letter to lowercase on blur but how we can mange in regex.

Comment: If you say "it is not accepting uppercase letters for https", do you mean that some letters of the word *https* are upper case?

Comment: @SparkFountain  OP just needs `[hH][tT]{2}[pP][sS]` instead of `https`